# How to save cluster of 5 elements into one attribute element in XML file?

Tags: labview

We have a LabVIEW cluster with 5 elements and I want to save these 5 elements into one attribute in an XML file.

[image: XML screenshot]

How can I do this?

Comment: Please post your XML file as text (formatted as code), not as picture. Also, it would be useful if you give the desired result.

Comment: Thanks ,i will post text data.

Comment: I am unable to post text data ,it is showing below error,Error:Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: The error message says it. After pasting your text, select it in the editor and press Ctrl+K (or the "{}" toolbar button)

Comment: Here you can see: [How do I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Edited to put the image inline and (hopefully) make the question clearer - please re-edit if this isn't what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LabVIEW's built in Flatten To XML node produces the XML shown in your question. That is the built-in schema and there are no controls to create an alternate schema.

You can install the free, open-source, third-party [EasyXML toolkit](https://github.com/JKISoftware/JKI-EasyXML) to be able to have the control you need to generate a more specific schema. http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/209021

Comment: That link goes to the 'JSONtext by JDP Science' toolkit which appears to generate JSON but doesn't mention XML - are you sure that's what you meant?

Comment: Cool. Have edited in the actual name of the toolkit (in case of link rot) and a link to the code and documentation on the JKI github page.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the LabVIEW Flatten to XML node is pretty lacking, generating something that's technically XML but not very semantically helpful.

Alternatively, it's not hard to write your own XML generator, especially since you'll know your cluster fields at compile time.

A Format Into String function should take care of your needs really effectively, I'd think.

http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361L-01/glang/format_into_string/